Full Authentication Is Requred to Access This Resource - Spring - Microsoft Graph API - App Only Permission
I am doing a project to read emails from Exchange using Microsoft Graph API in Java Spring.
So far , I've been following these tutorials :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/identity/enable-spring-boot-webapp-authorization-entra-id
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java?tabs=aad
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java-app-only?tabs=aad
I've set Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite, User.Read.All , all in app-only permission in API Permission, yet still failed.
I also tried Graph with delegated permission , EWS and Jakarta Mail way but keep returning Insufficient priviledge / Authentication Failed.
As far as I know , I input email and password correct.
Is there something I missing ?
Is there any alternative available ?
EDIT :


Could you confirm from what type of user account you are trying to access emails? personal Microsoft account or local account that ends with .onmicrosoft.com?

@Sridevi i am using at company.com which using exchange .. I've confirmed we are using full cloud service on exchange

Could you edit your question and add Portal images of API permissions from your app registration and user's properties overview image?

Could you share the code how do you authenticate?

@user2250152 i am following the code just like in the tutorial above, on app-only .. then I change the params of client_id, tenant id and client secret

the error occurs on getUser and / or getToken

There can be a company policy that blocks application access to mailboxes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

@Ray As you mentioned "the error occurs on getUser and / or getToken", could you confirm whether you are able to get access token or not? I followed same MS Doc and able to get users and token successfully like this https://i.imgur.com/8lZqDHx.png and https://i.imgur.com/GC5Y0vo.png

@user2250152 In the end, I'm using httpurlconnection and put the URLs according to each function. Though it's working, I still want to implement using GraphClient. As for the policy , the infra team confirmed that no specific limitation implemented on the account

@Sridevi No , I can't get the token using the example

Hi @Ray Any update?

Initially, I registered one application and granted same API permissions of Application type with consent as below:

Now, I created Java Spring project named microsoft-graph-demo using Spring Initializr and added below Maven dependencies:
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>microsoft-graph-demo</name>
    <description>microsoft-graph-demo</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.18.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
             <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>  
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>  
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Azure Identity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Microsoft Graph SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>5.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Open src/main/resources/application.properties and add below properties in it:
azure.graph.client-id=appID 
azure.graph.client-secret=secret
azure.graph.tenant-id=tenantID
spring.security.enabled=false

Now, navigate to src/main/java/com.example.microsoftgraphdemo/ and create classes with below code:
MicrosoftGraphService.java:
package com.example.microsoftgraphdemo;  
  
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;  
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;  
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;  
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Message;  
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;  
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.MessageCollectionPage;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;  
  
import java.util.Collections;  
import java.util.List;  
  
@Service  
public class MicrosoftGraphService {  
  
    @Value("${azure.graph.client-id}")  
    private String clientId;  
  
    @Value("${azure.graph.client-secret}")  
    private String clientSecret;  
  
    @Value("${azure.graph.tenant-id}")  
    private String tenantId;  
  
    private GraphServiceClient<?> graphClient;  
  
    // Initialize the Graph client  
  private void initializeGraphClient() {  
        if (graphClient == null) {  
            ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()  
                    .clientId(clientId)  
                    .clientSecret(clientSecret)  
                    .tenantId(tenantId)  
                    .build();  
  
            TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(  
                    Collections.singletonList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),  
                    credential  
            );  
  
            graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()  
                    .authenticationProvider(authProvider)  
                    .buildClient();  
        }  
    }  
  
    // Fetch emails for a specific user  
  public List<Message> getEmails(String userId) {  
        initializeGraphClient();  
        try {  
            MessageCollectionPage messages = graphClient.users(userId)  
                    .messages()  
                    .buildRequest()  
                    .get();  
  
            return messages.getCurrentPage();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching messages: " + e.getMessage(), e);  
        }  
    }  
}

MicrosoftGraphController.java:
package com.example.microsoftgraphdemo;  
  
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Message;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  
  
import java.util.List;  
  
@RestController  
public class MicrosoftGraphController {  
  
    private final MicrosoftGraphService graphService;  
  
    public MicrosoftGraphController(MicrosoftGraphService graphService) {  
        this.graphService = graphService;  
    }  
  
    @GetMapping("/emails")  
    public List<Message> getEmails(@RequestParam String userId) {  
        return graphService.getEmails(userId);  
    }  
}

SecurityConfig.java
package com.example.microsoftgraphdemo;  
  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;  
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;  
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;  
  
@Configuration  
public class SecurityConfig {  
  
    @Bean  
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
        http  
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth  
                        .requestMatchers("/emails").permitAll() // Allow public access to `/emails`  
                        .anyRequest().authenticated() // Protect all other endpoints  
  );  
        return http.build();  
    }  
}

When I ran the project and visited http://localhost:8080/emails?userId=<USER-ID> in browser, I got the response with user's emails successfully:

